# rails heroku connect database to phpmyadmin mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app that is working fine when connected to remote database. the database is mysql in phpmyadmin in another server. I made a query in my controller and display it in my view:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

   require 'mysql'

    helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
    protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

    def index
      p "BEFORE!!"
      con = Mysql.new '<username>', '<host>', '<password>', '<database username>'
      @user = con.query("SELECT * from username")
      p @user
    end
end
```

the query does working and @user does return the data from my remote database. But when I push my repo to heroku, I got an error.

I have also installed the DBClear MYsql add on and change the database_url pointing towards my remote database, but still error.

database.yml for all environment:

```
  adapter: mysql
  database: "<database name>"
  host: <database host>
  port: <db port>
  username: "<my own username>"
  password: "<my own password>"
  pool: <pool no>
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Check the heroku logs, looks for ways how you can view it. I cannot recall currently

Comment: What is the error message you get?